# How to calculate the percentage of daily total from two columns of different sizes and tables in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to group the values from the table below according to day

[image: Daily generation]

in order to calculate the daily percentage relative to the total, which is located in the table below

[image: Total generation capacity]

FYI,
Both tables are linked by the DUID variable (Many-to-one relationship)

[image: Relationship]

The final result should be the following:

[image: Final Result]

I did it in four steps:

1. Generated a Date Table;
2. Created three measures in the new Date Table:

Measure 1: `PASA_DAY = CALCULATE(SUM(MTPASA[PASAAVAILABILITY]))`
Measure 2: `TtlGenCpcty = CALCULATE(SUM('ExistingGeneration&NewDevs'[TotalNmPltCpcty]),ALL('ExistingGeneration&NewDevs'[TotalNmPltCpcty]))`
Measure 3: `Measure = DIVIDE('Date Table'[PASA_DAY],'Date Table'[TtlGenCpcty])`

Is there a way to do this in less steps?

Thank you in advance. I appreciate it.
Have a nice day :^)

Comment: I solved my question but it didn't give me what I wanted... :^(

`PASA%Cpcty = DIVIDE('MTPASA'[PASAAVAILABILITY],RELATED('ExistingGeneration&NewDevs'[TotalNmPltCpcty]))`

Let me think about how to reformulate my question and I'll edit it.
Cheers

Comment: I edited the question with my solution after learning that Measures are the way to go with PowerBI instead of calculated columns. Please let me know if you know a more efficient way to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: You could combine three measures into one. But, no need to really. What you've done here is a nice practice (I don't know if it is considered a best practice, but I split measures into smaller ones too, makes it easier to maintain).